# Django: Can't get urls.py working

Tags: django-urls

Django beginner, sorry:

My project's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import profiles.urls
import listings.urls
import accounts.urls
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.AboutPage.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^users/', include(profiles.urls, namespace='profiles')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(accounts.urls, namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^listings/', include(listings.urls)),
]
```

My app's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

http://localhost:8000/listings gives me an error "The localhost page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data."

I have no idea what went wrong here, I just can't get it to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in my views.py.  I had put Listing.all() instead of Listing.objects.all().

Answer (score 0):

You have to put "$" at the finish of regex, like this

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

on your project´s url: dont use the import

```
url(r'^listings/', include('listings.urls')),
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but still didn't work..Been googling for the past 60 minutes.  App is included in settings and I also have __init__.py.

Comment: Tried that, but still not working...Still says "The localhost page isn’t working" - I've also restarted by server.  Sorry I'm a n00b